# Network Configuration Get Removed After Restarting Zentyal Linux Server

Tags: wifi, network-interface, zentyal-linux

I'm facing a issue with my wireless configuration in Zentyal Linux Server. 
I configured my wifi network setting in /etc/network/interfaces like this :

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
wireless-essid <name>
wireless-key1 <key>
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
...
```

It is working fine but when i restart my Server. Network settings get removed every time and shows following lines only :

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Every time i have to write these settings again to start my wifi. What is going on, and how can I fix this ?

Comment: Zentyal has a web interface. I guess that the web interface overwrites configuration files, so you should either use the web interface or use Ubuntu if you want to configure things the normal way.

Answer (score 1):

Zentyal does not use "ordinary" configuration files; your setup will be erased every time you restart the server. In order to allow for admin-made configuration options, Zentyal allows for "hooks", scripts that will get executed along the main configuration files.

It isn't that complicated: if you have your wpa-supplicant already set up and working, just add this to your

```
/etc/zentyal/hooks/network.postsetconf
```

file (you can make a copy of one of the templates in that directory as well):

```
#!/bin/sh
export WLAN_IFACE="wlan0"
export WLAN_ESSID="YOUR_SSID"
export WLAN_CONF="wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf"
/usr/share/zentyal-network/setup-wireless
exit 0
```

That should now start up your wifi automatically.